# Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just updated my project to Angular-CLI and I am on:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.1",
```

I am getting an error saying:

> Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an
>   exported function angular CLI

from this `.ts` file:

> userManagement/userManagement.routing.ts

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'unlockUserID', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'unlockUserID',
        loadChildren: ()=> System.import('./unlockUserID/unlockUserID.module')
            .then((imports: any)=> imports.UnlockUserIdModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'changePassword',
        loadChildren: ()=> System.import('./changePassword/changePassword.module')
            .then((imports: any)=> imports.ChangePasswordModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'maintainOfficeHierarchy',
        loadChildren: ()=> System.import('./maintainOfficeHierarchy/maintainOfficeHierarchy.module')
            .then((imports: any)=> imports.MaintainOfficeHierarchyModule)
    },
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Than in my module:

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        SmartadminModule,
        routing,
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class UserManagementModule {

}
```

--------------------------------Update 1-----------------------------

Had to change it to this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'unlockUserID', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'unlockUserID',
        loadChildren: './unlockUserID/unlockUserID.module',
        data: {pageTitle: 'unlockUserID'}
    },
    {
        path: 'changePassword',
        loadChildren: './changePassword/changePassword.module',
        data: {pageTitle: 'changePassword'}
    },
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true});
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.
```

---------------------------Update 2---------------------------

I changed it to

`export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes)`;

Now I am getting an error saying:

```
 Cannot find 'default' in './changePassword/changePassword.module'
```

If I click on the changePassword tab, same for the other links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#arrow-function-exports-top

> Arrow function does not work with AoT when it is passed to an `NgModule`.

So you shouldn't define Arrow functions inside your `Routes`.

Comment: So I have to completely change the way routing is done in this project. By looking at the above, do you have any suggestions on a less painful way.

Comment: @Drew1208 I've never used lazy loading like that so I can't recommend anything but that seems to be the problem :/ If you want to read the routes from somewhere, you can maybe create a config file and add them there.

Comment: @Drew1208 are you using `forRoot` twice? Any sub routing modules?

Comment: @Drew1208 you need to have 1 root `forRoot` routing module and if you are using nested routing modules they need to be `forChild`. And I don't even know what your `changePassword.module` looks like

Comment: I just updated my post with that in update 2. Thank you for the response though. I got another error after I did that though. Upgrading to CLI has been a complete pain.

Comment: Are you interested in a job. Angular 4 and good pay. It is short term and on the side. Let me know

Answer (score 1):

For lazy loaded modules via the router, importing via string is deprecated.

ng update will take care of this automatically. The new syntax leverages the ecosystem wide support for import rather than our custom rewrites.

Your loadChildren route configs should be changed from a string such as

```
loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
```

to an import statement such as

```
loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
```